# How to highlight multiple lines of inline equations?

Tags: highlighting, soul

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color, soul}

% comment out one of the two: 
\newcommand{\myhl}[1]{\hl{#1}} % highlight
%\newcommand{\myhl}[1]{{#1}}      % don't highlight

\soulregister\Hl{7}
\soulregister\cite7
\soulregister\ref7
\soulregister\eqref7
\soulregister\pageref7



%\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
%    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{Title}

\author{ABC}

\markboth
{}{}

\corresp{Corresponding author: ABC (e-mail: abc@abc.com).}

\begin{abstract}
ABC\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
ABC\end{keywords}

\titlepgskip=-15pt

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
I want to highlight the following equation: $f(x)=x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x$.
This equation is blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
This equation is blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
\\~
\\
\myhl{I want to highlight the following equation: $f(x)=x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x$.
This equation is blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
This equation is blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.}

\EOD

\end{document}
```

The output of the above code is as follows:

[image]

How can I break the equation?
Thanks.

Comment: Please extend your code into something others can copy and test as is.

Comment: @daleif I edited my post.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to display the equation with `\[ ... \]`?

Comment: You can force a manual break with (note the space between closing and reopening `$`): `$f(x)=x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+$ $x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x$.`

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes, I do not want to make a new equation line. I want to leave the equation in the text line.